# How to redirect to another page if it is accessed directly? [PHP]

Tags: php, url, redirect

How to redirect a page to the homepage if it is accessed  directly (Without a variable)?
Suppose we have a link   "example.com/site?website=$_GET[variable]" if it is accessed like this then it is OKAY! but if someone tries to access it directly using this link "example.com/site" Then it should redirect to the Homepage.
How to do it?

Comment: Where is your code so far?

Answer (score 2):

```
if(isset($_GET['variable']) && !empty(trim($_GET['variable']))) 
{
//your rest of code
} else {
header("Location:redirectpage.php");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to check at the top of your script if the global $_GET variable is set (which it will be if any query string variables are set) and redirect if not.

```
if(!isset($_GET)):
   header("Location: /");
   exit(); 
endif;
```

You can just add that at the top of your code and if the query string is set then your code will carry on as normal.

Answer (score 1):

This is supposed to be a comment but i have a low reputation here.

I am a bit confused. But why dont you just check for the existence of the variable in the link
Like:

```
<?php
```

//add code below on every page or have it in a file and include everywhere
    $access = false;

```
if(isset($_GET['variable_name'])){
//obviously any one can pass any funny variable, so you will need to match it with your database to verify or the variable might be a unique word of some sorts.
   $access = true;
}else{
  $access = false;
}

if($access == false){
    die('No access to view this page');
}
```